# how to add/remove an entity's mapping programmatically

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-mapping

I have a handler which uses the same `Entity` for two different kind of queries:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_iso50k1.meter", schema="app_iso50k1")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="mettype", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"phy" = "PhyMeter"})
 */
abstract class Meter
{
    const TYPE_PHYSICAL = 'PHY';
    const TYPE_VIRTUAL = 'VIR';
    const TYPE_LOGICAL = 'LOG';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    <methods>
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PhyMeterRepository")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class PhyMeter extends Meter
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $idInstrum;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $idDevice;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $instrumType;

    ...<methods>
}
```

The first handler's method is performed on a legacy DB table and it would need to map all the fields annotated with `@ORM\Column` (`id`, `idInstrum`, `idDevice`, `instrumType`). To do that, I use a primitive query and I map the data by means of a `ResultSetMapping`

```
   $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
   $rsm->addEntityResult('Belka\Iso50k1Bundle\Entity\PhyMeter', 'mt');
   $rsm->addFieldResult('mt', 'id', 'id');
   ...
```

and it works like a charm. The problem is on the the other handler's methods which need to persist data on `app.meter` table: what I really would like to persist are a *small part* of the properties (i.e. just the `id`, `idInstrum` but not `instrumType` so as not to have that column in my new table's schema.

I was thinking about using `StaticPHPDriver` but I'm not sure if it is the right way: what I really would like is manually adding/removing some ORM mapping according to my needs (i.e. different handler's functions)

Is that possible? I could remove the mappings (`@ORM\column` annotation) I don't need to persist, but that way I cannot map the extra properties by using `ResultSetMapping`, unless I can add it programmatically.

Any hint is more than welcome